# AJAX bad request 400 error after post request (wordpress plugin)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm modifying an existing wordpress plugin, and I have to do an AJAX POST request in according to use a wordpress method.
I have to pass in the data field the action parameter, which should be handled by wordpress with the method `add_action()`.

The php handler function:

```
function my-function(){
   //my code with the wordpress method
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my-action','my-function');
```

The jQuery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'my-action'
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype: "json",

            success: function() {
               //do something if success
            },
            error: function(  ) {
                //do something if fail
            }
        });
```

In the main plugin file

```
wp_enqueue_script('comment_updater', plugins_url('ff_update_comment.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'));
wp_localize_script( 'comment_updater', 'ajax_object', array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
) );
```

The problem is that the call returns the following error:

> load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=4.9.2:4
>   POST http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad
>   Request)

I followed a lot of tutorials and documentation, the code seems to be correct as in the tutorials it works perfectly.

Comment: What's the body of your `my-function`? (I'm assuming that's not the real name as dashes are not allowed for function names)

Comment: Yes that's not the real name. Anyway the body could be everything you want, for example a simple echo "hello world". It is not executed.